# Linq query run over list of parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a requirement to create a linq query that selects data from a database table where a certain functional result is true.

I am using `linq-to-sql` and the function works well and I can write a basic query to get the data.

My issue is that I have an in-memory list of parameters and I essentially need to run the linq query multiple times (once for every parameter list item) and aggregate the results.

I have tried using the `.Any()` as a join but linq doesn't like joining non-database result sets with database result sets.

Some Sample Code:

```
Parameter list: // lets call it "l"
{    
 One,
 Two,
 Three
}
```

Query

```
From w in words where funcWord(l.item) == true select w;
```

So I would require a query that can run the above query once for every item in l and aggregate the results.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: your current query doesn't make any sense - what is the dependency of `funcWord(l.item)` to `w` ? And what is `funcWord` ?

Comment: Apologies for being vague. This query was only to provide an example and was the quickest example I could put together. To clarify funcWord is a sql function that returns a scalar value true / false base on some conditions. The code should read funcWord(l.item, w.name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx), which aggregates the result of a one-to-many function, applied to each member.

In this case, the members are the elements of `list`, and the one-to-many function is your above, `l`-dependent query (though I rewrote it as a lambda function.)

`list.SelectMany(l => words.Where(w => funcWord(l.item, w.name)));`

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `from` statements will go through every combination, sort of like nested `foreach` statements:

```
from item in list
from w in words
where funcWord(item, w.name) == true
select w;
```

Interestingly, this gets translated to a `SelectMany` statement that is similar to Arithmomaniac's answer.

Comment: Thanks Risky Martin. This is how I initially approached it but linq did not like me trying to join a database table and non-database table. Did this work for you?

Comment: @ narudnarud I'll admit that I don't know much about LINQ to SQL.  But now I'm curious why this solution doesn't work.  It gets translated to a `SelectMany` statement, not a `Join` statement.  Are you sure you didn't use the `join` keyword?